# Can someone write the code for n = 19 rows and get this following figure? For Python

Tags: python, for-loop, pascals-triangle

Write a function that accepts a number n as an input, and it returns n rows that look like the following pattern. Run your function for n = 19 (the output below is for n=19).

```
n = int(input("enter number of rows:"))
for i in range(1, n+1):
    for j in range(1, n-i+1):
       print(end=' ')
    for j in range(i,0, -1):
        print(''+str(j),end='')
    for j in range(2,i+1):
        print(str(j)+'_',end='')
    print()
```

Ouput

```
                  1
                 212_
                3212_3_
               43212_3_4_
              543212_3_4_5_
             6543212_3_4_5_6_
            76543212_3_4_5_6_7_
           876543212_3_4_5_6_7_8_
          9876543212_3_4_5_6_7_8_9_
         109876543212_3_4_5_6_7_8_9_10_
        11109876543212_3_4_5_6_7_8_9_10_11_
       1211109876543212_3_4_5_6_7_8_9_10_11_12_
      131211109876543212_3_4_5_6_7_8_9_10_11_12_13_
     14131211109876543212_3_4_5_6_7_8_9_10_11_12_13_14_
    1514131211109876543212_3_4_5_6_7_8_9_10_11_12_13_14_15_
   161514131211109876543212_3_4_5_6_7_8_9_10_11_12_13_14_15_16_
  17161514131211109876543212_3_4_5_6_7_8_9_10_11_12_13_14_15_16_17_
 1817161514131211109876543212_3_4_5_6_7_8_9_10_11_12_13_14_15_16_17_18_
191817161514131211109876543212_3_4_5_6_7_8_9_10_11_12_13_14_15_16_17_18_19_
```

[image]

Comment: have you tried it? show us an error and we can help you fix it.

Comment: Aha! it is your assignment in school. :D  We are not here to give you the answer but if you try doing it and got stuck, we can help.

Comment: yeah I got stuck, I can show you my code wait

Comment: I uploaded it to the question! I cant seem to replicate it.

Comment: You are adding an extra underline on the left side of your triangle.

Comment: n = int(input("enter number of rows:"))
for i in range(1, n+1):
    for j in range(1, n-i+1):
        print(end=' ')
    for j in range(i,0, -1):
        print('_'+str(j),end='_')
    for j in range(2,i+1):
        print(str(j)+'_',end='')

    
    print()

Comment: Your understanding of the assignment is not correct. You are missing rows that starts with _

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work and will give you a good answer on your assignment.

```
n = int(input("enter number of rows:")) 
r = 0
for i in range(1, int((n+1)/2+1)):
    r += 1
    for j in range(1, n-i+1):
        print(end='  ') 
    for kk in range(i,0, -1):
        if i==1:
            print(' '+str(i))
        else:
            if kk==i:
                print(end= ' ')
            if kk==1:
                print(str(kk), end='')
            else:
                print(str(kk)+'_', end='')
    for ll in range(2,i+1):
        if i>1:
            print('_'+str(ll), end='')
    if i>1:
        print()
    r += 1
    if r > n:
        break
    for jj in range(1, n-i+1):
        print(end='  ')
    for k in range(i,0, -1):
        if i==1:
            print('_'+str(i)+'_', end='')
        else:
            print('_'+str(k), end='')
    for l in range(2,i+1):
        if l==2:
            print('_'+str(l)+'_',end='') 
        else:
            print(str(l)+'_',end='') 
    print()
```

Result:

```
                                 1
                                _1_
                               2_1_2
                              _2_1_2_
                             3_2_1_2_3
                            _3_2_1_2_3_
                           4_3_2_1_2_3_4
                          _4_3_2_1_2_3_4_
                         5_4_3_2_1_2_3_4_5
                        _5_4_3_2_1_2_3_4_5_
                       6_5_4_3_2_1_2_3_4_5_6
                      _6_5_4_3_2_1_2_3_4_5_6_
                     7_6_5_4_3_2_1_2_3_4_5_6_7
                    _7_6_5_4_3_2_1_2_3_4_5_6_7_
                   8_7_6_5_4_3_2_1_2_3_4_5_6_7_8
                  _8_7_6_5_4_3_2_1_2_3_4_5_6_7_8_
                 9_8_7_6_5_4_3_2_1_2_3_4_5_6_7_8_9
                _9_8_7_6_5_4_3_2_1_2_3_4_5_6_7_8_9_
               10_9_8_7_6_5_4_3_2_1_2_3_4_5_6_7_8_9_10
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that works well. Since this looks like homework, I'll just give the algorithm.

```
For each row create a list of row * 2 + 1 size and fill with underscores
  Ex: row 0 -> [_], row 1 -> [___], row 2 -> [_____], etc
Find the middle of row and put 1 at the index
Then put 2 and indexes middle-2 and middle + 2
Put 3 and indexes middle-4 and middle+4
Repeat to finish row
   Ex: [_________] ->
       [____1____] ->
       [__2_1_2__] ->
       [3_2_1_2_3]
Print spaces - 1st row gets n spaces. 2nd row gets n-1 spaces, etc
Print the list
Repeat for next row
```

---

A slight improvement to this would be to just build the last line and then print slices of the last line in a loop. Starting from the middle and widening out.

---

I see you have accepted the other answer, so I assume you're have your assignment done so I can post my code.

```
n = 19
last_line = ['_'] * (n * 2 - 1)
middle = len(last_line) // 2
for j in range(0, n, 2):
    last_line[middle + j] = str(j // 2 + 1)
    last_line[middle - j] = str(j // 2 + 1)
for row in range(n):
    print(f"{' ' * (n - row)}{''.join(last_line[middle - row:middle + row + 1])}")
```

The first 6 lines of the code build the last line of the pyramid. And the last 2 lines prints slices of that.